# Implementing custom fields in a database for large numbers of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, custom-fields

I'm developing an app which requires a user defined custom fields on a contacts table. This contact table can contain many millions of contacts.

We're looking at using a secondary metadata table which stores information about the fields, along with a tertiary value table which stores the actual data.

Here's the rough schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomField](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContactAndCustomField](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContactID] [int] NULL,
    [FieldID] [int] NULL,
    [FieldValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

However, this approach introduces a lot of complexity, particularly with regard to importing CSV files with multiple custom fields. At the moment this requires a update/join statement and a separate insert statement for every individual custom field. Joins would also be required to return custom field data for multiple rows at once

I've argued for this structure instead:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [CustomField1] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [CustomField2] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [CustomField3] [nvarchar](max) NULL /* etc, adding lots of empty fields */
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContactCustomField](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldIndex] [int] NULL, 
    [FieldName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

The downside of this second approach is that there is a finite number of custom fields that must be specified when the contacts table is created. I don't think that's a major hurdle given the performance benefits it will surely have when importing large CSV files, and returning result sets.

What approach is the most efficient for large numbers of rows? Are there any downsides to the second technique that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Aren't [sparse columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Consideration_for_SQL_Server_2008_and_later:_Sparse_columns) exactly what you need?

Comment: Your current example is pretty much an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) implementation.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. Yes, its an EAV implementation, although I didn't know the correct name for that till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft introduced sparse columns exactly for this type of problems. Tha point is that in a "classic" design you end up with large number of columns, most of the NULLs for any particular row. Same here with sparse columns, but NULLs don't require any storage. Moreover, you can create sets of columns and modify sets with XML.

Performance- and storage-wise, sparse columns are the winner.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx

Comment: Sparse columns do not solve the problem that you have to have a fixed number of them in a table rather than the flexibility offered by having a one to many relationship between the entity and the attributes table, albeit at the cost of performance: Sparse columns are simply a better storage solution for columns where you might otherwise often have null values.

Comment: @StevePettifer the performance of sparse columns vs. EAV is likely much better in favor of sparse columns.

Comment: The problem of sparse columns is building the dynamically.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Empty unused columns don't cost a thing (ok, almost).

Comment: @MihaiStancu That's true but the OP is considering the choice of an EAV type model for flexibility or a denormalised model for performance. Whether they choose sparse columns or not will likely not be the biggest determining factor in the performance of the final solution, especially in terms of importing large amounts of data. They might choose to use sparse columns but only after they have decided on a model to use first.

Comment: @StevePettifer Sorry, I don't understand, you're preaching EAV? I've worked with both EAV, XML and sparse cols for open schema, EAV is by far the least robust and performant solution of these.

Comment: @dean I'm saying there are times when EAV is the best solution. Not many, but it happens. Sparse columns do not get you round the fact that if you need to dynamically add columns/attributes you cannot do this without a schema change, EAV does **but at the cost of performance** which I have repeatedly stressed. There's no reason why you couldn't use sparse columns in an EAV model but sparse columns themselves introduce an overhead in retrieving non-null values and therefore do not make sense in small numbers. Also EAV, whilst not fast, can be perfectly robust if you're careful.

Comment: thanks dean, we're probably going to go with sparse columns. I'd never even heard of them until yesterday. I've a lot to learn about this stuff =)

Answer (score 0):

uery performance. Query performance for any "property bag table" approach is funny and comically slow - but if you need flexibility you can either have a dynamic table that is changed via an editor OR you have a property bag table. So when you need it, you need it.

But expect the performance to be slow.

The best approach would likely be a ContactCustomFields table which has - fields that are determined by an editor.

Comment: +1 The 'property bag' approach is veering dangerously towards the EAV model which, while flexible, is often dog slow and a massive pain in the backside to develop, maintain and use, but sometimes there's just no getting away from it.

Comment: I use the same for data analysis - analysis runs have parameters. Sadly, those are not determined outside a analysis run. No other way to store them than the dreaded property bag ;( Sometimes a solution is terribly ugly - but the only usable.